# Example of a non-regular language that is a subset of a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

How can this be? I don't think it is actually possible for a non-regular language to be a subset of a regular language. What examples are there where this is true?

Comment: @Choirbean What context do you think might be required?

Comment: In fact, *any* infinite (regular) language has a non-regular subset. This can be obtained by forcing "growing gaps" between the length the strings in the chosen subset.

Comment: Don't we have like a dozen duplicates of this?

Comment: @Raphael The right column is always helpful: [Show that every infinite language has a non-regular subset](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33189).

Answer (score 5):

Every language over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is, by definition, a subset of $\Sigma^*$, which is regular. If you want a less trivial example,

$$\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}\subseteq L(a^*b^*)\,.$$